# FluentValidation - Check value is a date only if NOT NULL

Tags: datetime, fluentvalidation

I have a bool along with a nullable DateTime property.
The DateTime is only required if the bool is set to true...
And I want to validate the date if the bool is true.

I have this expression so far...

```
When(p => p.HasVisa == true, () => RuleFor(p => p.VisaExpiryDate).NotNull());
```

Now I try to validate the date in that expression using the .Must extension and my custom BeAValidDate method...

```
When(p => p.HasVisa == true, () => RuleFor(p => p.VisaExpiryDate).NotNull().Must(BeAValidDate));

private bool BeAValidDate(DateTime date)
{
  if (date == default(DateTime))
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

But the .Must extension doesn't allow me to operate on a DateTime that is nullable.
How do I do this sort of validation on a nullable date?

Comment: I've never used FluentValidation, but isn't your problem just that your `BeAValidDate` does not take `DateTime?` (ie a nullable DateTime) as a parameter?

Comment: LOL thanks Joachim, I was overthinking the whole thing, yes you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Joachim mentioned I need to have overloads for BeAValidDate that accepts both null and non-null dates.

```
private bool BeAValidDate(DateTime date)
{
  if (date == default(DateTime))
    return false;
  return true;
}

private bool BeAValidDate(DateTime? date)
{
  if (date == default(DateTime))
    return false;
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 35):

Just add ‘When’ to check if the object is not null:

```
RuleFor(x => x.AlternateNumber)
    .Must(IsAllDigits)
    .When(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.AlternateNumber))
    .WithMessage("AlternateNumber should contain only digits");
```

Comment: I know this is not the case, but for those cases in which you have more rules to set, you can use the DependentRules method

Answer (score 3):

This work for me:

```
RuleFor(user => user.DateOfBirth)
  .Must(p=> !(p == DateTime.MinValue))
  .WithMessage("DateTime not null");
```